# node.js console async app "best practice"

Tags: node.js, console, eventemitter

Periodically, I have to write node.js console applications that are meant to be run directly from the shell.  They do not accept input, they'll call the file system, do database calls and other async type activities.  Examples abound on how to set up node.js applications that are hosting a server and such, but for something that calls an async process, waits for it, and then exits after setting the exit code. I'm having a hard time finding what I would consider graceful examples.

Here is a snippet of how I'm addressing this for now.  Any node.js gurus have any cleaner ways to go about this, or is this mostly "ok"?

```
const emitter = new EventEmitter();
emitter.on('exit', (err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err instanceof Error ? err.message : err);
        process.exit(-1);
    } else {
        process.exit(0);
    }
});

setImmediate(async () => {
    try {
        await doSomeAsyncThing();
        emitter.emit('exit', null);
    } catch(e) {
        emitter.emit('exit', e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why you just don't use `Promise` `then` and `catch`, or if you want to use the async/await syntax: an async IIFE (`(async () => { })()`)?

Comment: Because I need to wait for the promise to finish.  From what I can tell, If I just doSomeAsyncThing().then(...) there is nothing to stop the console app from exiting (there is no ref/unref to keep the main event loop from exiting.

Comment: But there's no difference between `asyncThing().then()` and `await asyncThing()`.

Comment: Re-reading your comment, I missed the IIFE part.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of `unhandledRejection` event. It outputs `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and is expected to cause an exception in future Node versions by default. Since this is the intention here, it can be:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    console.error(err instanceof Error ? err.message : err);
    process.exit(-1);
});

(async () => {
    try {
        await doSomeAsyncThing();
        process.exit(0);
    } catch(e) {
        throw e;
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot about the whole pattern of (() => {})() I used to use with AngularJS modules.  Works like a charm!

Comment: You're welcome. Usually the recipe for top-level async IIFE in Node is `(async () => {})().catch(console.error)` but you need a rejection not to be caught here.